# How to remove submit button from a dialog opened for a web-item?

Tags: modal-dialog, atlassian-connect

The dialog opened for the web-item has a submit button and a cancel link in it.
I don't want the submit button to be present in the dialog.

How to do that?

The api provided by connect i.e.

```
AP.require('dialog', function(dialog){

    var submitButton = dialog.getButton("submit");

    submitButton.disable();

});
```

has methods only to enable/disable it.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the chrome of the dialog off when it's created via [dialog options](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/javascript/module-Dialog-DialogOptions.html). You would need to add your own buttons in once this has been done.